# How to add two for loops in a single table body in django template

Tags: python-2.7, django-templates, jinja2, django-1.11

```
<thead>
<th> username </th>
<th>place</th>
</thead>

{% for i, j in user_group1, user_group2 %}
<tbody>
    {% if i %}
    <td>{{ i.username }}</td>
    <td>{{ i.place }}</td>
    {% else %}
    <td>{{ j.username }}</td>
    <td>{{ j.place }}</td>
    {% endif %}
</tbody>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to use two for loops in a sinle table body. First i need to start the first one and after that i need to start the next one. how can i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Jinja2, you can join the two lists into one with the `+` operator:

```
{% for i in user_group1|list + user_group2|list %}
<tbody>
    <td>{{ i.username }}</td>
    <td>{{ i.place }}</td>
</tbody>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: but both of them are different queryset.

Comment: Convert the querysets to lists first then. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: it is not working. I think i am using other than jinja2. it giving me TemplateSyntaxError

Comment: I see. If you're using Django's built-in template then you simply have to combine the two querysets into one iterable and pass that iterable to the template instead. You can combine the two querysets with `itertools.chain`.

Comment: Plz help me with solving this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54264957/how-to-start-the-forloop-counter-from-a-different-index