# how to start the forloop.counter from a different index

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, django-templates, jinja2, django-1.11

I have  2 seperate forloops and i am using forloop.counter in bothloops. I want to start the second forloop counter from the ending of first forloop

```
{% for i in something1 %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
    <td>i.username</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
{% for j in something2 %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
    <td>j.username</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

if the first forloop ends at 10 then i want to start the next for loop from 11.plz help

Comment: Try using slicing, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6148636/3822311)

Comment: actually, i want to start the forloop counter  value from different index rather than start from 0 or 1

Comment: Your best bet is probably to combine the two lists in the view, then you only have to iterate over one thing in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not comfortable with Django, so I show a couple of option in plain Python, given the collections:

```
something1 = [1,2,3,4]
something2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

You can access objects by index (not the same as database index):

```
i = 1
for e1 in something1:
  print(e1)
  i += 1

for i2 in range(i,len(something2)):
  print(something2[i2])
```

Or slice the last collection:

```
for e1 in something1:
  print(e1)

for e2 in something2[len(something1):-1]:
  print(e2)
```

Of course, the last collection has to be the longest.

Answer (score 1):

Python's slicing features are quite extensive.
the syntax looks like that: `SOME_STRING[start:stop:step]`.
So basically you can use it pretty much however you like.

*I wanted to comment it on your comment, but unfortunately I don't have enough rep :)*